# Firebase push notifications not working for production on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I integrated Firebase Messaging SDK into my iOS project, created a push notification certificate for development and one for production, uploaded both p12 keys to Firebase and I do not receive the notifications, but just for development.

The code for registration is good, and it is the same I used for usual APNS, which worked fine.

The same behaviour happens for 3 applications.

Did someone else encounter this problem? Do you have any solutions or suggestions?

Comment: Ye, I encountered the same problem (push notifications delivered with APNS). No, still not working.

Comment: @CristiCh do you have any update working on that issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all check certificate which you are exporting. Typical mistake is to export private key and not a service.  I attached a screenshot. I hope that will save some time for you.

[Correct certificate to export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31iV9.jpg)

Comment: Yes, thank you! They click in the wrong place in [this article!](https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/)

Answer (score 34):

I had the same issue. Apparently there is an error in the Firebase documentation. **When you exporting the APN certificate for production** from your keychain to the .p12 file you have to **select the actual certificate, *not* the private key**.

Make sure you upload to the Firebase console this .p12 file in the Cloud Messaging APN certificate settings.

**Swift 4.0**

Also make sure you're using:

```
Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: .prod)
```

inside:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    #if DEVELOPMENT
        //Develop
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: .sandbox)
    #else
        //Production
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: .prod)
    #endif

}
```

Comment: This. This was the end of a two week search :)

Comment: This was the end of one day search :)

Comment: What do you mean about **select the actual certificate, not the private key**? Thanks in advance

Comment: @FlavioKrugerBittencourt I think this refers to the screen in KeyChainAccess program on OSX. When you select the certificate you have the option to drill down into details and see a key as a sub-item of the certificate. Instead of exporting the key, export the top-level certificate.

Comment: You've got to be kidding me, once again stackoverflow comes to the rescue. P.S. Firebase still hasn't changed the docs.

Comment: I only added APN key for development environment and forgot for production. Much thanks for the answer :D

Comment: the newer versions require this: [[FIRMessaging messaging] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRMessagingAPNSTokenTypeProd];

Comment: Thanks, its works for me.    
+ to test the prod notifications you have to test it via TestFlight.

Answer (score 3):

For me these steps resolved the same issue on production:

1. On Apple Developer portal go to Keys - > Add key
   [image]
2. Download your key, copy Key ID parameter
3. Open Firebase Console - > Project settings -> Cloud messaging
4. Upload your .p8 Key which you downloaded (step 2) here:
   [image]
5. On new window paste Key ID parameter and your App ID prefix as required

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by these steps:

1. Regenerate the profiles from the Apple developer portal
2. Remove the old ones
3. Update the new profiles on firebase console
4. Conform AppDelegate to the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate protocol
5. Make sure all the registration to APNS is done correctly (there are plenty of tutorials on how to do this)
6. Make sure you called configureFirebase at app startup
7. Send a message from the firebase console

It seems that step 4 does the difference.