# firebase react-native push notifications working for iOS release builds, but do not work in app released via App Store

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-native-ios

I have push notifications working as expected in a Google Play released version on Android with heads up display showing as expected.  I also have push notifications working as expected in a release build via Xcode.

The problem: push notifications do no appear as expected in an iOS build released via the App Store.

- I have created a new `APNs Authentication Key` and uploaded it to Firebase
- I have swizzling turned on
- Automatically signing enabled in Xcode
- same bundle id in Firebase, Xcode and plist

my package versioning:

```
"firebase": "^4.8.1",
"firebase-admin": "^5.7.0",
```

no errors or crashes, just no push notifications showing. I also updated firebase libraries, but not sure it had any effect.

[image: code signing identity in Xcode]

I'm not using certificates, and the Firebase suggested APNs Authentication Key:

[image: iOS app configuration]

[image: entitlements on archive as well as submitted build]

Comment: What do your code signing identity settings look like?

Comment: Also have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169460/firebase-push-notifications-not-working-for-production-on-ios

Comment: @peter-tao Please see edits to the original post for answers to both questions.

Comment: Try setting your Release Code Signing Identity to iOS Distribution. Archive the app, install an ad-hoc version to your phone, and test if push notifications can be received.

Comment: Okay, so the resolution to this problem is going to be provided by adding in some info to the original issue.  I am using the `firebase-admin` package and sending notifications via `admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, notification, options)`.  Using this I was adding in `content_available: true` which is how ios reads the aps payload and makes the app available even when in the background, however  the `firebase-admin` documentation parameter is actually `contentAvailable: true` and is mapped to ios correctly after that.

Comment: `TLDR`: So, in summation, `contentAvailable: true` must be set when using the `firebase-admin` and sending a data only payload push notification to an ios app that is in the background...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

So, in summation, `contentAvailable: true` must be set in the options param when using `firebase-admin` and sending a data only payload push notification to an ios app that is in the background via:

```
const options = {
  priority: "high",
  contentAvailable: true,   // NOT content_available: true
}


admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, notification, options)

...
```